# how to print a double level hash in ruby?

Tags: ruby, printing, hash

I meet a hash like this

```
{"num"=>"219", "id"=>"219", "name"=>"219", "key"=>"", "ps"=>["ˈɑ:bitrəri", "ˈɑrbɪˌtrɛri"], "sent"=>[{"orig"=>"\nHe makes unpredictable, decisions.\n", "trans"=>"\his decision is very hard to understand \n"}, {"orig"=>"\nYou can make an  choice.\n", "trans"=>"\n you can chose randomly。\n"}]}
```

I just want print a part of this hash.

my solution is

```
key = ['key','ps','sent']
key.each{|key| key == 'sent' ? (p server_config["sent"].to_s) : (p server_config[key])}
```

it does not work well.
the two level hash print like this

```
  [{\"orig\"=>\"\\nAs soon as he kicked the bucket, he started to become famous.\\n\", \"trans\"=>\"\\nhe die and he became famous \\n\"}, ]"
```

how to print this two level hash well

The output I want just like below.

```
As soon as he kicked the bucket, he started to become famous.

he die and he became famous.
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work well?

Comment: the two level hash print like this [{\"orig\"=>\"\\nAs soon as he kicked the bucket, he started to become famous.\\n\", \"trans\"=>\"\\nhe die and he became famous \\n\"},  ]"

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev thanks for your suggestion.I just edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

If the output format is not a constrait you can try the [pretty print](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/pp/rdoc/index.html) library:

```
require 'pp'

[ 'key','ps','sent' ].each do |key|
  PP.pp(data[key])
end
```

Comment: hi，thank for your help. However, I just want to enum this hash and print it with few key(not with all key).I have no idea with this two level hash.

Answer (score 0):

You have Array and Hashes embedded. I am showing you one way to approach it. Should get you started.

```
my_hash = {"num"=>"219", "id"=>"219", "name"=>"219", "key"=>"", "ps"=>["a:bitreri", "arbitreri"], "sent"=>[{"orig"=>"\nHe makes unpredictable, decisions.\n", "trans"=>"\his decision is very hard to understand \n"}, {"orig"=>"\nYou can make an  choice.\n", "trans"=>"\n you can chose randomly.\n"}]}

my_hash["sent"].each{|item| item.each {|key, val| puts val}}
```

Good luck!